# Multiple Modal Popups

Tags: modal-dialog

Would like to create multiple Modal popups.. the code below works for one popup but how would I go about doing 3 popups??  I'm just learning..  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal apparently the whole code won't paste.. using cellphone

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaaaaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Test</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
</div>

</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Another</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some Other Text..</p>
</div>

</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful for us to also see your HTML. There's nothing in the CSS that would prevent you from having three. Just 3 divs each with a class of "modal" should make 3 modals.

Comment: updated code..  you can try but it won't work..

Answer (score 0):

You would need to give each modal a unique id and bind the buttons accordingly. The three things that need to be duplicated and changed are

- the button id **id="myBtn"** to **id="myBtn2"**
- the modal id **id="myModal"** to **id="myModal2"**
- the javascript the selects buttons and modals by their id **document.getElementById('myModal');**

Right now, your two modals have the same id and ids are supposed to be unique. So if you want a second modal (and you expect to interact with that modal in JavaScript via its id) then you need to assign a unique id to the second modal.

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't seem to work.. I think the problem has to do with JavaScript honestly

Comment: @SemajRellim
Well it's not with JavaScript because I just did it here for you https://jsfiddle.net/Lnq6gtLb/ There are many ways to improve this code. I encourage you to spend the time dissecting what I did and thinking how to make it more efficient because it will help you improve as a developer. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot isick and yes it does help and I will play more to learn more thank you so much